# How to automate video generation out of short video clips (losless selection of highlights, add intro with title, end texts, captions)?

Tags: video, video-editor

I have a series of video clips that students created for their projects with embedded systems.

I'm seeking for a tool that would allow me to quickly select highlights, add transitions, add title and intro section, end text section, captions on highlights etc...).

As far as I have researched, [LosslessCut](https://mifi.no/losslesscut/) seems fine to select highlights. Is there any more complete tool or can I then use something else to add captions, music, intro and end sections with custom text for each clip (like project name, description, some photo of schematic, etc...) ?

Thanks in advance for advice, pointers to tools and other sources to learn from,
regards.

Comment: Welcome! Once you add titles and transitions, you will need to re-encode. There is no advantage to using a tool that can do lossless editing in that case.

Comment: Thanks for comment... But if all clips are of the same format, isn't it possible to concatenate/add segments with text, titles... Anyway, being lossless is not so important, if the tool is automated... I'm willing to wait... Will correct the title...

Comment: It doesn't matter what format the clips are. If you want to add titles and transitions that modify the source clips, you have to re-encode. If you only want cuts and you don't put titles over your source clips, then you can probably concatenate.

Comment: Hello, thanks for comment... I understand, re-encode is something I need... What are the tools for the job without lossless restricion ?

Comment: You can use any video editing software that you are comfortable with. If you need help narrowing the choices down, I'd suggest creating a new question with as many specific requirements as you can identify: free vs. paid, level of automation needed, operating system are all a good start.